# how to detect which row is concerned when changing autocomplete object inside datatable primefaces

Tags: events, primefaces, datatable, row, selecteditem

I have this datatable :

```
<p:commandLink value="ajouter Ligne" update="lesarticles"                       
                        process="@this" actionListener="#{commandeMB.addLigne}" />

                    <p:dataTable   id="lesarticles" var="car" widgetVar="carsTable"
                    rowKey="#{car.ligneCommandeFournisseurId}" selectionMode="single"
                        selection="#{commandeMB.selectedLigneCommandeFournisseur}"
                        value="#{commandeMB.commande.ligneCommandeFournisseurs}" 

                        >

                        <p:column headerText="Numero">

                            <p:autoComplete id="art" required="true" var="p"
                                itemLabel="#{p.numero}" itemValue="#{p}" dropdown="true"
                                requiredMessage="Valeur requise" value="#{car.article}"
                                forceSelection="true" converter="#{articleConverter}"
                                completeMethod="#{commandeMB.completeArticle}">
                                <p:column>#{p.numero}</p:column>
                                <p:column>#{p.designation}</p:column>

                                <p:ajax event="itemSelect"  listener="#{commandeMB.handleSelect}" 
                                update="designation unite pu" />

                            </p:autoComplete>

                            <p:message for="art" display="text" />

                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="designation">
                            <h:outputText id="designation"
                                value="#{car.article.designation}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="unité">
                            <h:outputText id="unite"
                                value="#{car.article.unite.libelle}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="PU">
                            <h:inputText id="pu" styleClass="monpu" 
                                value="#{car.PUAchat}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Quantité">
                            <h:inputText binding="#{qte}" styleClass="maqte" value="#{car.qte}"  >
                            </h:inputText>
                        </p:column>


                        <p:column headerText="Mt">
                            <h:outputText id="mt" styleClass="monmt"
                                value="#{car.mtLigne}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
```

I want when the user select one article(product in english) (througt autocomplete) I can detect which row is concerned by this selection to do do some treatements on managed bean side

as you see in the code I retrieve the selected article by :

```
    public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event){
    Article art = (Article) event.getObject();

}
```

but I want to retrieve also the row which contains this new article in the datatable

how can I achieve this

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<p:dataTable rowIndex="myIndex"/>
```

Then you can bind this value via;

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.index}" value="#{myIndex}"/>
```

Or;

```
<f:param name="myIndex" value="#{myIndex}"></f:param>
```

To be able to retrieve the value which comes with `f:param`:

```
Map<String, String> map = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        int index = Integer.parseInt(map.get("myIndex"));
```

You can put those in a `p:commandLink`, `p:commandButton` or `p:ajax`.

Comment: thank you for your response, I found another solution, what do you think :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by that :

```
<p:column headerText="Numero">

                        <p:autoComplete id="art" 
                            required="#{commandeMB.validation}" var="p"
                            itemLabel="#{p.numero}" itemValue="#{p}" dropdown="true"
                            requiredMessage="Valeur requise" value="#{car.article}"
                            forceSelection="true" converter="#{articleConverter}"
                            completeMethod="#{commandeMB.completeArticle}">
                            <p:column>#{p.numero}</p:column>
                            <p:column>#{p.designation}</p:column>

                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{commandeMB.handleSelect}"
                                update="designation unite pu mt" />

                        </p:autoComplete>



                        <p:message for="art" display="text" />

                    </p:column>
```

and in the managed bean I retrieve the concerned row by this :

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    LigneCommandeFournisseur ligne_concernee = 
    context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{car}", LigneCommandeFournisseur.class);
```